# javascript context menu in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, contextmenu

I have a problem with JQuery Context Menu ( [link text](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) ) and iframe.
If i use it inside, the context menu is naturaly shown inside. But it will be partialy shown.

I am searching how to resolve it.
Please note that the context menu only appear when i click on specific iframe's elements.

thanks :)

Comment: Can you show us your source code?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make sure the iframe page and the iframed page were on the same domain, then create the elements that made up the context menu in the parent page instead of the iframed page.